# Kingswaysoft SSIS create record with predefined GUID

Tags: ssis, guid, kingswaysoft

Is there a way to create a CRM record with predefined GUID via SSIS and Kingswaysoft?

I know this is possible via C#, by assigning ID property to new GUID.

If at all i create a column named ID, to which destination column it needs to be mapped?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, in order to populate a value to a record in SSIS using the KingswaySoft component, you would need to map a value from Upstream components. The same applies to GUIDs as well, unless you wish to populate a new GUID value for the field. In that case, you can simply leave it unmapped. In the case of predefined GUIDs, if you wish to provide values in a static way, then you may need to map the value using a Derived Column component. Could you let us know your specific use case and we can let you know our thoughts?

Alternatively, you can reach out to [our Support team](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) and we'd be more than happy to review the details with you.

Comment: Its so stupid of me, i over looked the ID column, just tried it able to load the GUID's like any other column. Thanks for your response.

Comment: We're glad to help and happy to see that you solved the problem. Thank you for contacting our Support team!